# springdatarepository ElasticSearch works on save but fails on update with java.lang.StackOverflowError: null

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-jpa, jackson, jhipster

I am getting `java.lang.StackOverflowError: null` when updating my data through `springdataelasticsearch`. The application was generated using `Jhipster 7.0.1`. Spring Boot version is `2.4.4.`. It works fine when creating a new object but an update results in error. Here is the relevant portion of `CountryAdminUnitTypeService.java`.

```java
     * Save a countryAdminUnitType.
     *
     * @param countryAdminUnitType the entity to save.
     * @return the persisted entity.
     */
    public CountryAdminUnitType save(CountryAdminUnitType countryAdminUnitType) {
        log.debug("Request to save CountryAdminUnitType : {}", countryAdminUnitType);
        CountryAdminUnitType result = countryAdminUnitTypeRepository.save(countryAdminUnitType);
        countryAdminUnitTypeSearchRepository.save(result);
        return result;
    }
```

When **creating**, here's how the object looks on call to `countryAdminUntiTypeSearchRepository.save(result);`.

```
result = {CountryAdminUnitType@23268} "CountryAdminUnitType{id=200102, name='Province'}"
   id = {Long@23292} 200102
   name = "Province"
   parent = null
   country = {Country@23275} "Country{id=183778, name='Turkey', isoCode='TR'}"
    id = {Long@23281} 183778
    name = "Turkey"
    isoCode = "TR"
    countryAdminUnitTypes = null
```

And here's how it looks on **updating**.

```
result = {CountryAdminUnitType@24746} "CountryAdminUnitType{id=200102, name='Province'}"
 id = {Long@24752} 200102
 name = "Province"
 parent = null
 country = {Country@24754} "Country{id=183778, name='Turkey', isoCode='TR'}"
  id = {Long@24756} 183778
  name = "Turkey"
  isoCode = "TR"
  countryAdminUnitTypes = {PersistentSet@24761}  size = 1
   0 = {CountryAdminUnitType@24746} "CountryAdminUnitType{id=200102, name='Province'}"
    id = {Long@24752} 200102
    name = "Province"
    parent = null
    country = {Country@24754} "Country{id=183778, name='Turkey', isoCode='TR'}"
```

The only difference I see is that `countryAdminUnitTypes` is not null in second case. However this should be taken care of by `JsonIgnoreProperties` given in **Country.java** below.

Here's the beginning of a very long log file.

```
ERROR 91444 --- [  XNIO-5 task-1] c.s.c.s.CountryAdminUnitTypeService      : Exception in save() with cause = 'NULL' and exception = 'null'

java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at org.springframework.data.util.Streamable.stream(Streamable.java:87)
    at org.springframework.data.util.Streamable.lambda$map$1(Streamable.java:101)
    at org.springframework.data.util.LazyStreamable.stream(LazyStreamable.java:55)
    at org.springframework.data.util.LazyStreamable.iterator(LazyStreamable.java:46)
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:74)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.MappingElasticsearchConverter.writeCollectionValue(MappingElasticsearchConverter.java:710)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.MappingElasticsearchConverter.getWriteComplexValue(MappingElasticsearchConverter.java:620)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.MappingElasticsearchConverter.writeProperty(MappingElasticsearchConverter.java:601)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.MappingElasticsearchConverter.writeProperties(MappingElasticsearchConverter.java:553)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.MappingElasticsearchConverter.writeEntity(MappingElasticsearchConverter.java:511)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.MappingElasticsearchConverter.writeEntity(MappingElasticsearchConverter.java:636)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.MappingElasticsearchConverter.getWriteComplexValue(MappingElasticsearchConverter.java:627)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.MappingElasticsearchConverter.writeProperty(MappingElasticsearchConverter.java:601)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.MappingElasticsearchConverter.writeProperties(MappingElasticsearchConverter.java:553)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.MappingElasticsearchConverter.writeEntity(MappingElasticsearchConverter.java:511)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.MappingElasticsearchConverter.writeEntity(MappingElasticsearchConverter.java:636)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.MappingElasticsearchConverter.getWriteComplexValue(MappingElasticsearchConverter.java:627)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.MappingElasticsearchConverter.lambda$writeCollectionValue$7(MappingElasticsearchConverter.java:709)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:1812)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.lambda$initPartialTraversalState$0(StreamSpliterators.java:294)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$AbstractWrappingSpliterator.fillBuffer(StreamSpliterators.java:206)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$AbstractWrappingSpliterator.doAdvance(StreamSpliterators.java:161)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.tryAdvance(StreamSpliterators.java:300)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$1Adapter.hasNext(Spliterators.java:681)
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:74)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.MappingElasticsearchConverter.writeCollectionValue(MappingElasticsearchConverter.java:710)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.MappingElasticsearchConverter.getWriteComplexValue(MappingElasticsearchConverter.java:620)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.MappingElasticsearchConverter.writeProperty(MappingElasticsearchConverter.java:601)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.MappingElasticsearchConverter.writeProperties(MappingElasticsearchConverter.java:553)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.MappingElasticsearchConverter.writeEntity(MappingElasticsearchConverter.java:511)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.MappingElasticsearchConverter.writeEntity(MappingElasticsearchConverter.java:636)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.MappingElasticsearchConverter.getWriteComplexValue(MappingElasticsearchConverter.java:627)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.MappingElasticsearchConverter.writeProperty(MappingElasticsearchConverter.java:601)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.MappingElasticsearchConverter.writeProperties(MappingElasticsearchConverter.java:553)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.MappingElasticsearchConverter.writeEntity(MappingElasticsearchConverter.java:511)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.MappingElasticsearchConverter.writeEntity(MappingElasticsearchConverter.java:636)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.MappingElasticsearchConverter.getWriteComplexValue(MappingElasticsearchConverter.java:627)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.MappingElasticsearchConverter.lambda$writeCollectionValue$7(MappingElasticsearchConverter.java:709)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:1812)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.lambda$initPartialTraversalState$0(StreamSpliterators.java:294)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$AbstractWrappingSpliterator.fillBuffer(StreamSpliterators.java:206)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$AbstractWrappingSpliterator.doAdvance(StreamSpliterators.java:161)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.tryAdvance(StreamSpliterators.java:300)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$1Adapter.hasNext(Spliterators.java:681)
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:74)
```

Here are the model classes.

**CountryAdminUnitType.java**

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Cache;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CacheConcurrencyStrategy;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.FieldType;

/**
 * A CountryAdminUnitType.
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "country_admin_unit_type")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
@org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Document(indexName = "countryadminunittype")
public class CountryAdminUnitType implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "parent", "country" }, allowSetters = true)
    private CountryAdminUnitType parent;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(
        value = { "defaultResidenceMeasurementUnit", "countryAdminUnitTypes", "preferences", "personNationalities" },
        allowSetters = true
    )
    private Country country;

    // jhipster-needle-entity-add-field - JHipster will add fields here
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public CountryAdminUnitType id(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
        return this;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public CountryAdminUnitType name(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        return this;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public CountryAdminUnitType getParent() {
        return this.parent;
    }

    public CountryAdminUnitType parent(CountryAdminUnitType countryAdminUnitType) {
        this.setParent(countryAdminUnitType);
        return this;
    }

    public void setParent(CountryAdminUnitType countryAdminUnitType) {
        this.parent = countryAdminUnitType;
    }

    public Country getCountry() {
        return this.country;
    }

    public CountryAdminUnitType country(Country country) {
        this.setCountry(country);
        return this;
    }

    public void setCountry(Country country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    // jhipster-needle-entity-add-getters-setters - JHipster will add getters and setters here

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(o instanceof CountryAdminUnitType)) {
            return false;
        }
        return id != null && id.equals(((CountryAdminUnitType) o).id);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        // see https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-implement-equals-and-hashcode-using-the-jpa-entity-identifier/
        return getClass().hashCode();
    }

    // prettier-ignore
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "CountryAdminUnitType{" +
            "id=" + getId() +
            ", name='" + getName() + "'" +
            "}";
    }
}
```

**Country.java**

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.persistence.*;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Cache;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CacheConcurrencyStrategy;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.FieldType;

/**
 * A Country.
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "country")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
@org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Document(indexName = "country")
public class Country implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "iso_code")
    private String isoCode;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "country")
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "parent", "country" })
    private Set<CountryAdminUnitType> countryAdminUnitTypes = new HashSet<>();

    // jhipster-needle-entity-add-field - JHipster will add fields here
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Country id(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
        return this;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public Country name(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        return this;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getIsoCode() {
        return this.isoCode;
    }

    public Country isoCode(String isoCode) {
        this.isoCode = isoCode;
        return this;
    }

    public void setIsoCode(String isoCode) {
        this.isoCode = isoCode;
    }

    public Set<CountryAdminUnitType> getCountryAdminUnitTypes() {
        return this.countryAdminUnitTypes;
    }

    public Country countryAdminUnitTypes(Set<CountryAdminUnitType> countryAdminUnitTypes) {
        this.setCountryAdminUnitTypes(countryAdminUnitTypes);
        return this;
    }

    public Country addCountryAdminUnitType(CountryAdminUnitType countryAdminUnitType) {
        this.countryAdminUnitTypes.add(countryAdminUnitType);
        countryAdminUnitType.setCountry(this);
        return this;
    }

    public Country removeCountryAdminUnitType(CountryAdminUnitType countryAdminUnitType) {
        this.countryAdminUnitTypes.remove(countryAdminUnitType);
        countryAdminUnitType.setCountry(null);
        return this;
    }

    public void setCountryAdminUnitTypes(Set<CountryAdminUnitType> countryAdminUnitTypes) {
        if (this.countryAdminUnitTypes != null) {
            this.countryAdminUnitTypes.forEach(i -> i.setCountry(null));
        }
        if (countryAdminUnitTypes != null) {
            countryAdminUnitTypes.forEach(i -> i.setCountry(this));
        }
        this.countryAdminUnitTypes = countryAdminUnitTypes;
    }


    // jhipster-needle-entity-add-getters-setters - JHipster will add getters and setters here

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(o instanceof Country)) {
            return false;
        }
        return id != null && id.equals(((Country) o).id);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        // see https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-implement-equals-and-hashcode-using-the-jpa-entity-identifier/
        return getClass().hashCode();
    }

    // prettier-ignore
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Country{" +
            "id=" + getId() +
            ", name='" + getName() + "'" +
            ", isoCode='" + getIsoCode() + "'" +
            "}";
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I'm facing the same issue, did you solve this?

Answer (score 1):

This is because of how JHipster sets up `save`. It was only happening on updating objects with bi-directional relationships.

```java
    * Save a countryAdminUnitType.
    *
    * @param countryAdminUnitType the entity to save.
    * @return the persisted entity.
    */
    public CountryAdminUnitType save(CountryAdminUnitType countryAdminUnitType) {
        log.debug("Request to save CountryAdminUnitType : {}", countryAdminUnitType);
        CountryAdminUnitType result = countryAdminUnitTypeRepository.save(countryAdminUnitType);
        countryAdminUnitTypeSearchRepository.save(result);
        return result;
    }
```

The object to be updated is set correctly when being passed to `jpa repository countryAdminUnitTypeRepository.save(countryAdminUnitType);`. However, the returned `result` object has circular dependencies and is directly forwarded to `elasticsearch repository countryAdminUnitTypeSearchRepository.save(result);` for update. I resolved it by only using the `id` of the object.

Line

```java
CountryAdminUnitType result = countryAdminUnitTypeRepository.save(countryAdminUnitType);
countryAdminUnitTypeSearchRepository.save(result);
```

has been changed to

```java
CountryAdminUnitType result = countryAdminUnitTypeRepository.save(countryAdminUnitType);
countryAdminUnitType.setId(result.getId());
countryAdminUnitTypeSearchRepository.save(countryAdminUnitType);
return result;
```

Comment: Nice solution, thank you. Do you have any thoughts on how to do it with annotations in entities? I suppose that's because JsonIgnoreProperties are ignored at this point for bidirectional ManyToOne or OneToMany relationships. This bug actually breaks initially generated jhipster app that uses elasticsearch and should be elevated to main thread of the project I suppose. Might solve this soon myself but maybe you got solution already? Regards

Comment: Here is a more general solution to the problem on official thread: https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/16136#issuecomment-1012404392

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the discussion. This did not work for me on entity , using Jhipster 7.8.1.
FYI, I just commented out the SearchRepository.save(result); as a quick fix to unblock development.

Issue: https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/16136#issuecomment-1012404392